# Vector functions. How do I graph $r(t) = \langle t+1, t-5\rangle$

Tags: calculus, vectors

I am trying to understand Vector functions beyond the trivial textbook definition of magnitude and direction, with the same tired example of a plane flying in a cross-current.  Surely, there must be more than this one application of actually using a vector to model something real.

- I understand the basic idea of magnitude and direction.
- I also get the (0,0) component vector concept.  $V=\langle v1,v2\rangle$
- I understand parametric functions.  eg: $x=f(t)$ and $y=f(t)$

Parametric:
$r(t) = (f(t), g(t))$ or written as $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$, then I get it.
For each value of $t$, you can have a distinct $x$ and $y$ and you can plot them.

However, what is the idea behind vector functions??

What does that even mean?

What I don't get is:  $r(t) = \langle f(t), g(t)\rangle$

For example, if I had:

$r(t) = \langle t+1, t-5\rangle$

At $t=1$, $r =  \langle 2,-4\rangle$

At $t=2$, $r= \langle 3,-3\rangle$

What does that even mean?

How would you graph that?
At $t=1$, I would have a vector drawn from $(0,0)$ to $(2,-4)$ ?

At $t=2$, I would have a vector drawn from $(0,0)$ to $(3,-3)$ ?

Would you have an infinite number of component vectors coming out of the origin?  This doesn't sound right.   What is that even supposed to be representing?  Does anyone have an actual real world situation I can use to try understanding what an infinite # of vectors can even represent?

Comment: For $r(t)=\langle f(t),g(t)\rangle$, we usually just draw a dot in the plane at the end of the arrow (starting at the origin).  Then $r(t)$ represents a point moving through the plane with respect to time.

Comment: Depending on the context one is interested in the arrows starting from the origin (e.g. location vector), sometimes in the arrow starting on the trajectory (e.g. tangent vector), sometimes only in the endpoint of the arrow (e.g. for the points of the trajectory).

Comment: Ok, so when you draw the component vector, you only draw the end point?  If so, what is the entire point of the vector?  Why not just define it as a parametric function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what's bothering you:

> If we're actually interested in the location of a *point* $(f(t),g(t))$ (a point on a line, in this case), why insist on writing it as a *vector* $\langle f(t),g(t) \rangle$?

The reason why this is done in many books is that they want to write the parametric equation of a straight line as
$$
\langle x(t),y(t) \rangle
= \langle a+tu,b+tv \rangle
= \langle a,b \rangle
+ t \langle u,v \rangle
,
$$
and in order to do the splitting in the last step, they need to use **vector** algebra.

Personally, I find this rather artificial, since we actually think of the *points* $(x(t),y(t))$ and $(a,b)$, and it's only the direction $\langle u,v \rangle$ that's "really" a vector. But to write it in a more natural way, one would have to introduce a new algebraic operation, **point + vector = point**, like this:
$$
(x(t),y(t))
= (a+tu,b+tv)
= (a,b)
+ t \langle u,v \rangle
.
$$
Apparently many authors consider this to be too confusing for students, since it's almost never seen in elementary textbooks. But as a price for avoiding this algebraic operation, you get other types of confusion, like blurring the distinction between points and vectors, and having to introduce an origin $O$ which really has nothing to do with the matter.

(Compare the nice and clean "point plus vector" equation $$P = P_0 + t \mathbf{v}$$ to the artificial-looking "pure vector algebra" equation $$\vec{OP} = \vec{OP_0} + t \mathbf{v},$$
where you need to pick an arbitrary point $O$ at which to "anchor" your vectors.)

Comment: I guess this is all very hard to understand without a concrete application.  I've seen one example of parametric where x(t) and y(t) for something like a simple parabolic arc.  I have seen one example of a vector (but not in Calculus) where you make a parallelogram from the 2 vectors and use some trig to find the resultant vector.  I have not seen any example of a vector function or why anyone would ever need one, so I really am unable to follow your point.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, you gave a concrete application in your question: $\langle x,y \rangle= \langle  t+1,t-5 \rangle$. This is intended to be interpreted as the equation of a straight line: as $t$ varies, the *endpoint* of the vector moves in a straight line (if the starting point is held fixed at the origin). And what I'm saying as that you are right in feeling that this is strange. You have a "fan" of infinitely many vectors coming out from the origin, but this is not how one should think of it; it's the *points* on the line that are interesting. And I tried to explain the reason for why...

Comment: ...textbook authors write it in this strange way.

Comment: If you want some interesting applications where vectors really play a role, think of *vector fields*: at each point $(x,y,z)$ there is a vector $\langle u,v,w \rangle$, so $u$, $v$ and $w$ are all functions of $x$, $y$ and $z$. Vector fields are used for describing all sorts of things, like electric fields, velocity in fluids, etc.

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure why you'd bother with vectors if you're not drawing the "fan" of vectors, but only the end points.  If you're only drawing the end points, just have a parametric function.  Seems like the same thing, unless an actual example demonstrates otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Translate that into a "normal" function of one variable:

$$y=t-5\,,\,\,x=t+1\implies y=x-6$$

and all you have to do now is to draw the above line. Mind you, this is far to be this simple in all cases, but sometimes it is.

Comment: So, vector functions are interchangeable with traditional functions?  If so, why bother?

Comment: You will see why, perhaps, when you reach multiple integration, differential geometry and etc. Also, read what I wrote in the last two lines.

Comment: I guess this is all very hard to understand without a concrete application.  I've seen one example of parametric where x(t) and y(t) for something like a simple parabolic arc.  I have seen one example of a vector (but not in Calculus) where you make a parallelogram from the 2 vectors and use some trig to find the resultant vector.  I have not seen any example of a vector function or why anyone would ever need one, so I really am unable to follow your point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Such functions are graphed in the same manner as parametric functions. For each value of $t$, there is a dot at the point $\langle t+1,t-5\rangle$. The vector from the origin to this dot is imagined because, as you suggest, having an infinite number of vectors starting at the origin and extending outward would be awkward and unhelpful. If the vector function is continuous, or at least mostly so, you will end up with a curve in the plane, or in the case of the example you gave, a straight line.

If you are interested in more engaging examples of the use of vectors, you should turn to classical mechanics in physics. Start with free-body diagrams. If you know some calculus, you could then learn about electromagnetism and fluid mechanics.

Comment: Ok, so when you draw the component vector, you only draw the end point?  If so, what is the entire point of the vector?  Why not just define it as a parametric function?

Comment: For the purposes of algebra a beginning calculus, you may think of a parametric function and a parametric function as the same thing.

Comment: I guess this is all very hard to understand without a concrete application.  I've seen one example of parametric where x(t) and y(t) for something like a simple parabolic arc.  I have seen one example of a vector (but not in Calculus) where you make a parallelogram from the 2 vectors and use some trig to find the resultant vector.  I have not seen any example of a vector function or why anyone would ever need one, so I really am unable to follow your point.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors are quite useful. Let me try to explain -

*I hit hard* is a complete sentence. *I hit him hard* is another complete sentence. The first sentence doesn't have any importance to many. The second sentence does. The first one is similar to a scalar, while the second one is a vector.

Using parametric form is nothing but writing a vector of say $2$ dimensions in terms of another quantity *t* with which we can form the original vector by taking various values for *t*.

Let me try that with an example again. *I gave $10$ coins and $5$ coins* is a scalar. *I gave $10$ coins to personA and $5$ coins to personB* is a vector. *I gave to personA $5$ coins more than to personB* is representing in parametrics.

I hope I was clear. I tried.

Comment: That is a good one.!!! Except that I didn't get the parametric part.

Comment: This didn't clarify a single thing.  I already understand magnitude and direction.  What is the point of a vector function?   Can you exactly come up with a specific example that could describe something in real life (besides an airplane and cross wind) ?